# How to take backup of current sheet or workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Hy, I have an excel workbook which consists of six worksheets. Everything is working fine in the workbook. I have written a macro which helps me to take the backup of current workbook instead of the current worksheet. The code is as under.

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim i As Long

    'Find the position of the period in the file name
    i = InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")

    'Create a default file name by concatenating the file name without the extention _
        plus the current date and time, and plus the xlsm extention
    Filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh mm") & ".xlsm"

    'Open Save As dialog to a default folder with default file name
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .FilterIndex = 2  '2 = xlsm
        .InitialFileName = "Report" & Filename
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = -1 Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

It is working fine for taking backup of workbook instead of the current working sheet without losing any data or formate or setting in the worksheet.
I have two problems.
1- When I click on the backup button, the active workbook is closed and backup workbook is opened.
2- I tried my best to take the backup of the current working sheet without losing any data or formating but I cloud not do so because everything when I click on the backup button for the current worksheet (I have written another macro to take backup for current worksheet but it is not working so I did not write it here) is lost.

What I want to do. I want to do two things.
1- When I click the backup button, the original worksheet remain open while the backup worksheet should remain close, so that I can take different name backups from same master worksheet.
2- If possible, I want a macro which helps me to take the backup of the active sheet without losing any data or information on the sheet.

Please guide where i am doing wrong. Thanks for every member.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try,

Sub FileSaveAs()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Fn As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Fn = Wb.FullName
    Wb.Save
    
    
    'Find the position of the period in the file name
    i = InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")

    'Create a default file name by concatenating the file name without the extention _
        plus the current date and time, and plus the xlsm extention
    Filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh mm") & ".xlsm"

    'Open Save As dialog to a default folder with default file name
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .FilterIndex = 2  '2 = xlsm
        .InitialFileName = "Report" & Filename
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = -1 Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
        .Execute
    End With
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Workbooks.Open (Fn)
    Wb.Close (0)
End Sub
```